# LayoutParams placing views in weird locations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I currently have a RelativeLayout within my application which I dynamically move, resize, and hide. After moving it once, the layout is repositioned to a weird location afterwards.

Here is the layout that I am using.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/moveable_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the code that I use to relocate it

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight);
m_movingFrame.setEnabled(true);
m_movingFrame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
m_movingFrame.setX(newX);
m_movingFrame.setY(newY);
m_movingFrame.requestLayout();
m_movingFrame.bringToFront();
m_movingFrame.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

And here is the code used to hide the layout

```
m_movingFrame.setEnabled(false);
m_movingFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

The first time that I relocate it, it moves to the correct position, but every subsequent relocation moves it to the wrong location. Can anyone tell me why it is behaving so erratically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Didn't you asked this question already?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't get any responses so I recreated it with a more specific title.

Comment: Please don't do that, edit and improve your original question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I wasn't sure how else to bump the question up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the layout of the existing layout and then modify it.

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) m_movingFrame.getLayoutParams();

...

m_movingFrame.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to partially work. However, when adding Rules, it appears to change the parent of the view. For example, setting `layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);` the first time will center the view, but if I move it somewhere and then center it again, then it will be shifted off somewhere else